# Rails joins and multiple associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, left-join

I have two `has_many` associations to another table:

```
has_many :sent_requests, foreign_key: :requester_id, class_name: 'FriendRequest'
has_many :pending_requests, foreign_key: :target_id, class_name: 'FriendRequest'
```

I want to eagerly load these associations, but `includes` didn't help.

Here is request from logs:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

I tried next:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN friend_requests as sent_requests 
       ON sent_requests.requester_id = users.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN friend_requests as pending_requests 
       ON pending_requests.target_id = users.id")
```

But this doesn't seem to fill my associations correctly. I see multiple users for each `friend_request`.

How can I load my associations?

Comment: What SQL is being generated from the `has_many`? Your example from the logs shows a `User.find(1)` or perhaps `User.first` type request, not anything to do with the `sent_requests` or `pending_requests` associations which you appear to be trying to optimize.

Comment: User.find(1) should work, because I've put includes and joins into default scope